# Finding values to make an equation with a $x^4$ into a perfect square

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring, perfect-powers

For what values of p and q is the expression $$x^4+ 6x^3+ 13x^2+ px + q$$ a perfect
square?
The answer I got didn't seem correct so if someone break it down to me how about going this problem it would be appreciated

Comment: Why do you think that having $2$ roots is bad?

Comment: yeah no I just realized I was thinking of something different. I do maths through another language and it was my own misunderstanding that confused me here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: write like this

$$x^4+ 6x^3+ 13x^2+ px + q= (x^2+ ax +b)^2$$

$$=x^4+ 2ax^3+ (2b+a^2)x^2+ 2abx + b^2$$

---

So $a =3$ and $2b+9 = 13$ so $b= 2$. Then $p = 2ab =12$ and $q=b^2 =4$.